# can't build update site using tycho when use root.folder

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I'm trying to build an update site using tycho. This update site includes one feature. When I tried to build the update site it was built successfully.

But in the feature I want a certain file to be exist inside the eclipse root after installation of this update site.

So I wrote this in the `build.properties` file in the feature:

```
root.folder.try = file:try.exe
```

But it gave me a build error.

I packaged the update site using `eclipse-repository` and the feature using `eclipse-feature`.

Answer (score 1):

The build.properties entry `root.folder` is [not supported](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/BuildProperties.html). However you easily get the same effect with the an `root` entry:

1. Create the folder you want in the installation as folder in your sources (in your example `try/`)
2. Move the file you want to have included into that folder (in your example `try.exe`)
3. Create a `root` build.properties entry which includes the folder. Example

   ```
   root=try
   ```

When installing the feature that has the build.properties into an Eclipse installation, the `try/try.exe` will be automatically installed.

Comment: Can you get try.exe in the Eclipse root this way?

Comment: @PawelPogorzelski: Yes, this is possible in principle, but not what is being asked for here.

Comment: Indeed, looks like "root" entry supports both scenarios. +1